# Images of lines in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under linear map are lines or points?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ a linear map and $R_0=\{t\vec{x}+\vec{y}_0\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $R_1=\{t\vec{x}+\vec{y}_1\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ two different parallel lines that through by $\vec{y}_0,\vec{y}_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ its director vector.

How to prove that:

1. The images $L(R_0)$ and $L(R_1)$ are both points or both straight lines. Describe the conditions that give either case.
2. In the case that $L(R_0)$ and $L(R_1)$ are straight lines, this are parallel? Justify your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in R_0$. So, $L(x_0) = L(tx + y_0) = tL(x) + L(y_0)$.

Let $x_1 \in R_1$. So, $L(x_1) = L(tx + y_1) = tL(x) + L(y_1)$.

If $L = 0$, both images will be points. Otherwise, both images will be straight lines with direction $L(x)$.

As $L(R_0)$ and $L(R_1)$ have the same direction $L(x)$, they are parallel.

Comment: why if $L\neq 0$ both $L(R_0)$ and $L(R_1)$ can not be points?

Comment: Because if $L \ne 0$, then $L(a) = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0$, i.e., it maps only the zero to the zero. All the other vectors will be mapped to a non-zero vector.

Comment: If $L\neq 0$ then $L(R_0)=\{L(y_0)\}$ and $L(R_1)=\{L(y_1)\}$ both are points. The problem no say that $0\in R_0\cap R_1$.